# how to add background color to last line of GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, itext

I am using iText to export GridView to pdf. 
I was able to add header color to my pdf.

I would like to add background color to the last (total) line/row of pdf in the Gridview?

I am using iText library to export GridView to Pdf.

Here is my pdf function :

```
public void ExpToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getHTMLGridView();
}

private void getHTMLGridView()
{    
    BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
    iTextSharp.text.Font times16 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Texas Tech University", times16);
    p1.Alignment = 1;


    iTextSharp.text.Font times14 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Department of Institutional Research", times14);
    Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph(caption.Text.ToUpper(), times14);
    p2.Alignment = 1;
    p3.Alignment = 1;

    //iTextSharp.text.Font times10 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);
    //Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("(Uncertified Data)", times10);
    //p4.Alignment = 1;

    Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph("   ");

    iTextSharp.text.Font times8 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK);

    iTextSharp.text.Font times11 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE);

    iTextSharp.text.Color BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CC0000"));


    PdfPTable HeaderTable = new PdfPTable(4);

    //actual width of table in points

    HeaderTable.TotalWidth = 600f;

    //fix the absolute width of the table

    HeaderTable.LockedWidth = true;

    //relative col widths in proportions - 1/3 and 2/3

    float[] Headerwidths = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};

    HeaderTable.SetWidths(Headerwidths);

    HeaderTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

    //leave a gap before and after the table

    //HeaderTable.SpacingBefore = 30f;

    //HeaderTable.SpacingAfter = 30f;    

    foreach (TableCell cell in MyGridView.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Text, times11));

        // Set the PDF cell backgroundcolor to GridView header row BackgroundColor color
        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;

        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right

        // Add the cell to PDF table
        HeaderTable.AddCell(pdfCell);

    }



    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

    //actual width of table in points

    table.TotalWidth = 600f;

    //fix the absolute width of the table

    table.LockedWidth = true;
    //relative col widths in proportions

    float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};

    table.SetWidths(widths);

    table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

    //leave a gap before and after the table

    //table.SpacingBefore = 30f;

    //table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

    string connect = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringExtracts_IRDW"].ConnectionString;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
    {

        string query = "dbo.sp_FB_APPADM_IRDW";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportType", reportType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term_Code", ENRDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        try
        {
            int i;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            // Fill the DataSet.
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    PdfPCell pdfCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row[i].ToString(), times8));

                    pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
                    // Add the cell to PDF table
                    table.AddCell(pdfCell4);
                }
                for (i = 2; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    PdfPCell pdfCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row[i].ToString(), times8));

                    pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = 2; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right

                    // Add the cell to PDF table
                    table.AddCell(pdfCell4);
                }


            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex.Message);

        }

        //Create the PDF Document
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

        //open the stream
        pdfDoc.Open();

        //add the table to the document
        pdfDoc.Add(p1);
        pdfDoc.Add(p2);
        pdfDoc.Add(p3);
        pdfDoc.Add(p5);
        pdfDoc.Add(HeaderTable);
        pdfDoc.Add(table);

        //close the document stream
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=Enrollment_Major_Classification.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();

    }


}
```

I tried using:  `GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1]` to get the last row of `gridview`. But, I did not seem to make my way around it, to add color to last row.
Any help much appreciated.

[image: pdf]

Comment: Can you be specific? Do you just want to change color for last row? Which color? 
Maybe just show the relevant code that you have tried.

Comment: just like i added color ( #CC0000) to header, i want to add color to last row of this GridView.

Comment: yes, i just want to add color to last row.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1].BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Or if the row is a FooterRow:

```
GridView1.FooterRow.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: did not work, the footer color in pdf did not change.

Comment: `iTextSharp.text.Color BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CC0000"));` 

This is how i have defined my background color in my code.